# How do i check the response from a list

Tags: discord.py

I was creating a bot with codes to enter. But how do i check if the message content contains 1 of the codes in the list?

this is what i have now:

```
@bot.command(name='get')
async def get(ctx):
    await ctx.send('Enter your code')
    msg = await bot.wait_for('message')
    if msg.content == ['code1', 'code2']:
        await ctx.send('Here is your treasure!')
    else:
        await ctx.send('That code is invalid')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `in` keyword:

```py
>>> a = 2
>>> mylist = [1, 2, 3]
>>> a in mylist
True
>>> mylist.remove(2)
>>> a in mylist
False
```

And applied to your case:

```py
@bot.command(name='get')
async def get(ctx):
    await ctx.send('Enter your code')
    msg = await bot.wait_for('message')
    # converting to lower case - make sure everything in the list is lower case too
    if msg.content.lower() in ['code1', 'code2']:
        await ctx.send('Here is your treasure!')
    else:
        await ctx.send('That code is invalid')
```

I'd also recommend adding a `check`, so that you know the message is from the original author, in the same channel etc:

```py
@bot.command(name='get')
async def get(ctx):
    await ctx.send('Enter your code')

    def check(msg):
        return msg.author == ctx.author and msg.channel == ctx.channel

    msg = await bot.wait_for('message', check=check)
    if msg.content.lower() in ['code1', 'code2']:
        await ctx.send('Here is your treasure!')
    else:
        await ctx.send('That code is invalid')
```

---

**References:**

- [`Client.wait_for()`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Client.wait_for)
- [`Message.channel`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Message.channel)
- [`Message.author`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Message.author)